# Amazon Aurora MySQL conditional comment queries

Tags: mysql, aws, aurora

How does Amazon Aurora handle conditional queries based on MySQL version? I was unable to find any documentation on this.

For example, the code below inserts into a database for MySQL 5.6.4 or newer. What is result in Aurora?

I could spin up an instance but wanted to read the documentation about this to understand what incompatible features there are.

```
/*!50604 REPLACE INTO `phppos_app_config` (`key`, `value`) VALUES ('supports_full_text', '1')*/;
```

Comment: What is the problem with `REPLACE` in Aurora?  (Please provide link.)

Comment: It isn't a problem with replace I just want to make sure the query isn't ignored as I don't think Aurora follows the same versioning of mysql and all I want to know is if there query will run and not be ingored

Comment: Then simply try it:  `SELECT /*!50604 "inside comment", */ NOW();` -- You will either see `inside comment` or not.  The current time will show up in either case, as confirmation that the query was executed.

Comment: I just booted up an Aurora instance and it was running 5.6.10 and it worked. I was hoping not to boot one up as I don't need it; but it will only cost a small amount. This might help someone else when they have this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Aurora runs as mysql 5.6.10a so the comment queries still work as expected in regular mysql